# How to delete list of tables from table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis using Latex, in my thesis I don't have any table, however list of table title appears. How to exclude it? and suggestions?

Comment: Do you have `\listoftables` in the document, if so delete it. If not then a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for your problem may be needed. In particular, which class are you using (can you link to where it can be found online if it's non-standard/not on CTAN).

Comment: It's in this link:
http://www.kfupm.edu.sa/deanships/dgs/Pages/thesis_manual.aspx

Comment: What a nice template.  With overfull boxes and undefined references by default!

Comment: The class file provides an email adress for comments and bugs of the class. Please write them an email and politely inform them that the template needs some serious attention. If a template loads the very same package three times within less than ten lines, you can  be sure the template is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file `kfupm_thesis.cls`, search for the lines

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}LIST OF TABLES}{\pageref{ListofTables}}}
\label{ListofTables}
\listoftables

\eject
```

and comment them out.

```
% \addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}LIST OF TABLES}{\pageref{ListofTables}}}
% \label{ListofTables}
% \listoftables

% \eject
```

Don't forget to run latex twice for the changes to show their effect.

Comment: Thank you. It runs fine
Since you work in it, can you solve an other problem?

Comment: The abbreviation does not appear!!

Comment: @Ahmed Feel free to ask another question on this platform. I'm sure that someone here will help, maybe me, whoever has the time and expertise. But please don't ask follow-up questions in the comments. It is difficult to provide all the information for describing the problem.

Comment: The abbreviation does not appear!!

Comment: @Ahmed Please ask a separate question and provide enough information. At the moment I don't know to which abbreviation you refer. In your new question, provide the source code of a complete small document (starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`) that illustrates the problem, and describe what's wrong and how you expect it to behave.

Comment: I put the question here, because it refers to the same templae [Thesis Template],

Comment: @Ahmed Still, the fact remains that "The abbreviation does not appear!!" does not contain enough information for me to help in any meaningful way. Moreover, the way how this site works is by asking one question per thread and by providing adequate information. But feel free to wait and see whether someone picks up your second question.

Comment: @Ahmed It might be the same template, but it is a different question. PLease ask it as such.

Answer (score 0):

After `\documentclass[...]{kfupm_thesis}` add

```
\newenvironment{preamble}{%
\setstretch{1.5}
%\thispagestyle{plain}
%\pagenumbering{roman}
\eject
\tableofcontents

\eject

\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}LIST OF TABLES}{\pageref{ListofTables}}}
\label{ListofTables}
\listoftables

\eject

%\addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {}LIST OF FIGURES}{\pageref{ListofFigures}}}
\label{ListofFigures}
\listoffigures

\eject

\setstretch{2}

}{%
\eject
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\eject
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but there is an error and it does not run

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
\documentclass[ms, 12pt]{kfupm_thesis}
\let\listoftables\relax
[...]
```

Comment: Not sufficient. The `\addcontents` command still adds a line to the toc.